Image as plane disappearing behind each other
I have imported a map and flags with 'image as plane'. Some flags are disappearing behind the map, even tho they are in frond of it. How is this possible?






You'll need to pack the images into your Blend file with File External >Data > Pack Resources so that we can see the images. Also which version of Blender are you using?

okey. I use version 3.6.5

Each of the image textures in the scene are using an unnecessary Alpha channel which is causing the alpha sorting issues.
To fix this, open a Shader editor then in the 3D viewport select a flag, go to the Shader editor and disconnect the Alpha input of the Principled BSCF shader node.
Or alternatively in the Material Properties panel > Settings > uncheck Transparency Overlap option.


You will need to do this for all the flags and the map textures.

That does not work. There is no Transparency Overlap option

OK I missed your comment where you mentioned that you were using Blender 3.6.5.

Show Backface needed to be unchecked.


You could  change the (Material properties > Settings >) Blend Mode from the default Alpha Blend to Alpha Clip instead of unchecking Show backface.
